# Right rotation for 2D array

Tags: arrays, c, rotation, right-to-left, shift

I tried to code a right rotation for a 2D array.

Here is the main code:

```c
for (int k = 0; k < rotate; k++) { //rotate is the no of times to shift right
   for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) { //n1 is no: of rows
        for (int j = 0; j <n2; j++) { //n2 is no: of columns

            //Shifting right
            int temp = A[i][n2 - 1]; 
            A[i][n2 - 1] = A[i][j + 1];
            A[i][j + 1] = A[i][j];
            A[i][j] = temp;
        }  
    }     
}

for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
        printf("%d", A[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

It is working for size 2x2 where:

**Input:**

```
1 2
3 4
```

**Output:**

```
2 1
4 3
```

But it's not working for size 3x3 and above.

**Input:**

```
1 2 3                                                                                                                                        
4 5 6                                                                                                                                
7 8 9
```

**Output:**

```
3 2 1                                                                                                                                   
6 5 4                                                                                                                                    
9 8 7
```

Where **expected output** is:

```
3 1 2
6 4 5
9 7 8
```

Please guide me about where I'm wrong and I apologize for any mistakes in my question.

Comment: This line `int temp=A[i][n2-1]; ` should be put before the `j` loop

Comment: Note that it will be easier for us to test the programme and help you if you provide a minimum working example

Answer (score 1):

See:

https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/examples/matrix-transpose ;)

You can change that solution to use one array.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are referring to both left and right neighbours (though left one is wrongly referred because it should be last cell only for first interation) and don't keep value for next iteration.

It should be implemented as follows:

For each row `left` is initalized with the value of very last item in the row, because it is on the left of 0th item. Then while iterating over row items we first save current value to `temp` to use it later, then save `left` to current item, and then use previosly saved `temp` as new `left` for next iteration.

```
for (int k = 0; k < rotate; k++) { //rotate is the no of times to shift right
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) { //n1 is no: of rows
        int left = A[i][n2 - 1]; 
        for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++) { //n2 is no: of columns

            //Shifting right
            int temp = A[i][j];
            A[i][j] = left;
            left = temp;
        }  
    }     
}
```

Comment: Can u please tell what is prev ?

Comment: Sorry, it should have been `left`, I edited my answer.